# JQuery Templates need to assign ID's

Tags: c#, wcf, jquery-templates

This is probably dead simple I'm just not on the right track I bet.

I have an array of JSON objects being returned from my WCF calls, read by a JQuery AJAX call.

Lets say the object looks like this:

```
string Name
string BackgroundImage
```

So I have a bunch of spans I want to lay down in my webpage and I want to give them unique IDs.  I was able to do it this "bad" way by 
throwing an ID into my json object

```
    $("#tabLink").tmpl(json.d).appendTo("#nav");
```

--

```
    <script id="tabLink" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
        <span id="page{$id}" class="tabLinks" style="background-image:url(${BackgroundImage}")>Tab {$id}</span>
    </script>
```

I want to see:

```
<span id="page1" class="tabLinks" style="blahblahblah")>Tab {$id}</span>
<span id="page2" class="tabLinks" style="blahblahblah")>Tab {$id}</span>
<span id="page3" class="tabLinks" style="blahblahblah")>Tab {$id}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pass an object containing the array to your template.  Then, do your "each" in the template where you have $index available to you or you can explicitly keep track of the index and object.

Would be like:

```
<script id="tabLink" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
      {{each items}}
        <span id="page${$index}" class="tabLinks" style="background-image:url(${BackgroundImage}")>Tab ${$index}</span>
      {{/each}}
 </script>
```

or:

```
<script id="tabLink" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
      {{each(i, item) items}}
        <span id="page${i}" class="tabLinks" style="background-image:url(${BackgroundImage}")>Tab ${i}</span>
      {{/each}}
</script>
```

And called like:

```
$("#tabLink").tmpl({ items: json.d }).appendTo("#nav");
```

Sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JHACF/

Doesn't seem like $index is available when just passing an array to .tmpl, otherwise you would be set with just using $index.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way, but it seems a little hacky..

before my .appendTo() I can add a prop in .js so that one is not needed in WCF..

```
    var x = 1;
    $.each(json.d, function (i, item) {
        item.ID = x++; 
    });
```